# Hibernate Connection

Tags: mysql, jsf, hibernate

Estou tentando fazer uma aplicação usando o **hibernate**, mas quando vou criar o arquivo **.cfg.xm**l ele não reconhece o driver do **mysql**, mesmo estando na minha pasta de **lib** o conector do **mysql**.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguem poderia me ajudar, desde já grato!

Comment: Qual a versão do driver que você colocou na pasta lib? Tentou dar um refresh no projeto?

Comment: @Douglas estou usando o seguinte driver: **mysql-connector-java-5.0.8.jar** sim já tentei refresh.

Comment: Não sei o que pode ser mas observe que na mensagem ele especifica a versão `5.0.0`. Troque o seu por essa versão e veja o resultado.